# how to solve the emotion problem with typescript and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I am trying to create tokens with emotion but it is not working, I believe because of the typescript, because in javascript files it works. Does anyone know how to solve?

My theme:

```
import '@emotion/react';

export const palette = {
  common: {
    black: '000',
    white: 'fff'
  }
```

my component:

```
    import styled from '@emotion/styled';
    
    import { theme } from '../../utils/theme';    
         

      export const button = styled.button`
           background: ${({ theme }) => theme.pallete.common.black};
        `;
```

error:

```
Property 'pallete' does not exist on type 'object'
```

Comment: You are exporting `const palette` but you are importing `theme` and then doing nothing with `theme`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo

```
Property 'pallete' does not exist on type 'object'
```

while the name is `palette`

Try fixing the name

Comment: hi, it was a typo here, the code is correct and the error continues

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can type your component like this.

```js
interface Pallete {
 common: {
   black: '#000'
 }
}
export const button = styled.button<{ pallete: Pallete }>`
  background: ${({ pallete }) => pallete.common.black};
`;
```